# How to install Pytorch and SciKit-image on Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (with Python 3.9.2)

Tags: python, pytorch, raspberry-pi, scikit-image, raspberry-pi4

I am facing a problem installing both `Pytorch` and `scikit-image` on my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B with `Python 3.9.2`. I have tried several methods but they all failed.

I have tried installing `Pytorch` following these websites, but I still can't get it:

- https://qengineering.eu/install-pytorch-on-raspberry-pi-4.html
- https://medium.com/secure-and-private-ai-writing-challenge/a-step-by-step-guide-to-installing-pytorch-in-raspberry-pi-a1491bb80531

For these two resources, I got `ERROR: torch-1.12.0a0+git67ece03-cp39-cp39-linux_aarch64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

- https://gist.github.com/akaanirban/621e63237e63bb169126b537d7a1d979
- https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-scripts/blob/master/pytorch_jetson_install.sh
- https://github.com/Kashu7100/pytorch-armv7l

For these resources, I got

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
error: 1240 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

For the `scikit-image` installation, my Raspberry Pi totally stucked and stop operating with the screen on [everything stopped working, including the time, but the screen was on]. This problem was found after I installed `openblas` when `error: dependency openblas was not found` was generated from my first try. I have to force shut down it everytime I wanted to install `scikit-image` after the `openblas` installation.

[UPDATE (5 Dec 2022): I have installed meson-python but it still stucked during the installation]

The whole installation will stuck at `Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ...` [the raspberry pi will not function and I have to force shutdown it by unplugging the power source] and the temperature of my raspberry pi will increase to +- 52 degree during the installation of `scikit-image`.

Comment: Can you add the error messages you are receiving to your question?

Comment: I will update my outputs in my post. Please have a look there.

Comment: Allright, that's looking better! Just one thing (it's important for the quality of this website). Don't post images of code/errors, the reasons why are explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Edit your question and then we can take a proper look :)

Comment: Okie, I have edited my question. Please have a look.